$\left\{z_n\right\}$such that $f\left(z_n\right)=g\left(z_n\right)$, $\left\{z_n\right\}$ has a limit point in $\Omega$, then $f(z) \equiv g(z)$ .

Let $f$ and $g$ be meromorphic on a connected subset $\Omega$ of $\Bbb C$. If there exists a sequence $\left\{z_n\right\}$ of $\Omega$ such that $f\left(z_n\right)=g\left(z_n\right)$, and  $\left\{z_n\right\}$ has a limit point in $\Omega$, then $f(z) \equiv g(z)$ .

My attempt: Let $F=f-g$, then $F(z_n)=0$, and $F$ has only at most countable poles. Let $z_n\to z_0\in \Omega$,
if $F$ is holomorphic at $z_0$, then $F(z_0)=0$ (this is not true, since may $f(z_n)=\infty=g(z_n)$), but we could not use the uniquness result of holomorphic function, since $F$ is just meromorphic...Oh.
if $z_0$ is a pole of $F$, then contradicts with the isolated singularity, OK?
If $F$ has just isolated singularities, then...

Presumably $\Omega$ is actually a domain, not just a connected subset.  (I'm not even sure what the presiding definitions would be for a non-domain)

In the context of meromorphic functions, we usually define the sum (resp. difference) of two meromorphic functions to be the continuous extensions of their point-wise sum (resp. difference).  In this way, $F$, appropriately defined, is meromorphic on $\Omega$.
As a result of [WLOG] $z_n \to z_0 \in \Omega$ and $F(z_n) = 0$, $F$ cannot have a pole at $z_0$, so it is holomorphic there and $F(z_0) = 0$.
As a result of the identity theorem, applied to meromorphic functions on a domain, $F\equiv 0$.
